# How to set application fragments to portrait mode only?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Android app which has a main activity and 3 Fragments which are tabs. I would like the application to remain in portrait mode at all times but I can't seem to get this working. This is what I have tried, as per another stack overflow post, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong....does it need to be different if using fragments?

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.tutorial.test.activities.act1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thank you!!

Edit: The ViewPager is on the FragmentActivity for which I am setting the screenOrientation as above.

Comment: are you not able to get that done through `android:screenOrientation="portrait`?, I think that should work...

Comment: Nope, screen still flips to landscape when I turn the phone...could it be because of the fragments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this..

You can try with **programmatically**.

After `rootView` in your java add this line `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

For **Ex**:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activityxml, container, false);       
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And also in your manifest change it `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` as `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tutorial.test.activities.act1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" >
```

Comment: You could change orientation in onAtach() and change back to original one in onDetach()  so orientation changes only when fragment is on.

Answer (score 1):

Orientation attribute is per activity so you can declare the orientation for only the activity that contains the fragment so that it is in landscape and the rest of the activities will remain as they are.

getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

or you can declare in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Control" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```