# portrait and landscape orientations and set android:configChanges="orientation" in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, orientation

I have specific layout & layout-land files for both portrait and landscape orientations and set `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity in manifest file to stop `oncreate()` to execute in fragment.
Android will automatically destroy and recreate activity on an orientation change, and so each call to `onCreate()` will get the right layout.
I have Main ActivityFragment which contains 4 Tab having fragments as orientation changes `onCreate()` get call and re-create it.But I dont want to get call to `onCreate()` but need the layout orientation change using layout & layout-land files.

Is any way to achieve this..

Comment: Try this Example Given By @Hariharan. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950135

Answer (score 0):

The following method is called when you override using configChanges.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Check the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout );
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but I need to recreate the view in it and handle its event.Where I have a web service onCreateView(). And don't want to call but just have orientation feature using layout files

Comment: When you add configChanges to manifest, onConfigurationChanged() method is called when orientation changes but the activity is not recreated. And you need to change any layouts yourself.

Comment: Edited answer to include how you can set new layout.

Comment: ok. AS you say, I need to add layout myself with this I need to initialize the objects and Widget Click and list data which is coming from web service. Its a good way to call web service again and again on orientation change?

Comment: It won't call the web service again and again if you add android:configChanges to your manifest.

Comment: but it wont take layout from layout-land file

Comment: yes, I have. I am just doing the same. I am using fragment
 v =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);
But it wont take the other layout

Answer (score 0):

As you know, if you set android:configChanges="orientation" Then on orientation change the activity and in turn fragments are not going to be restarted.

So, if you are in portrait mode and change to landscape mode, it will retain your portrait layout itself. so your landscape mode layout(from layout-land) will not be used. And similarly in case from landscape mode to portrait mode.

So, What you are trying to achieve is not the ideal approach.

Since, you want the layout to change, you must save the states(data) of each fragment and **onConfigChanges** populate the data back so that appropriate layout is selected.