# Fragment orientation always portrait

Tags: android, fragment

I restricted the activity orientation change via

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But a fragment is attached to this activity.

How can I restrict the fragment from changing its orientation?
Because it's looking odd in landscape, therefore I want it to be always in portrait mode.

Comment: Fragments do not have an orientation. Please explain what "looking odd in landscape" means. You may wish to take some screenshots, upload them somewhere, and link to them from your answer.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting as well.

Comment: I just want that fragment should be in portrait. Is it possible @CommonsWare

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950070/how-to-set-application-fragments-to-portrait-mode-only